# Django, how to calculate the total of each line

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I would like to calculate 'total' for each line. with the following code, it shows only last line total, not each line total. this in case we have many products in this invoice. need total of each product (price*quantity)

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
client = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def total(self):
    items = self.invoiceitem_set.all()
    for item in items:
        amount_due = (item.price * item.quantity)
    return round(amount_due, 2)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
```

HTML

```
{% for product in object.invoiceitem_set.all %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{product.product}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{object.total}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the same value because you're calculating the total for the entire invoice and showing that each time. So, to separate it out you might want to try the following (if I'm understanding you correctly):

add a total function to the InvoiceItem class:

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):

    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)

    def total(self):
        return round(self.price * self.quantity, 2)
```

And the html becomes

```
{% for product in object.invoiceitem_set.all %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{product.product}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
    <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{product.total}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: if i want to add another <td>{{product.weight}}</td> which is on 'Product' table and i want it to calculate the total weight <td>{{product.total_weight}}</td> (total_weight=weight*quantity)